# Is there a way to save and reload browser appcache state?

Tags: mobile, web, chrome

On any browser, mobile or desktop. Just curious. Knowing how to do this or if this is possible would make my life way easier for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are solutions for desktop browsers

---

- **Chrome**: [Google Chrome Backup](http://www.parhelia-tools.com/products/gcb/googlechrome.aspx)
- **Firefox**: [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com) and [build-in profiles functionality](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles)
- **Safari**: [Safari Backup And Restore](http://www.downv.com/Mac/download-Safari-Backup-Restore-10031477.htm)
- **Internet Explorer**: [BackRex Internet Explorer Backup](http://www.backsettings.com/internet-explorer-backup.html)
- **Opera**: [OperaFly](http://operafly.software.informer.com)